# Joomla zoo Alphaindex New Line

Tags: php, joomla

this is joomla 2.5 zoo business alphaindex xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alphaindex other="0-9">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
    <option>d</option>
    <option>e</option>
    <option>f</option>
    <option>g</option>
    <option>h</option>
    <option>i</option>
    <option>j</option>
    <option>k</option>
    <option>l</option>
    <option>m</option>
    <option>n</option>
    <option>o</option>
    <option>p</option>
    <option>q</option>
    <option>r</option>
    <option>s</option>
    <option>t</option>
    <option>u</option>
    <option>v</option>
    <option>w</option>
    <option>x</option>
    <option>y</option>
    <option>z</option>
    <option>ა</option>
    <option>ბ</option>
    <option>გ</option>
    <option>დ</option>
    <option>ე</option>
    <option>ვ</option>
    <option>ზ</option>
    <option>თ</option>
    <option>ი</option>
    <option>კ</option>
    <option>ლ</option>
    <option>მ</option>
    <option>ნ</option>
    <option>ო</option>
    <option>პ</option>
    <option>ჟ</option>
    <option>რ</option>
    <option>ს</option>
    <option>ტ</option>
    <option>უ</option> 
    <option>ფ</option>
    <option>ქ</option>
    <option>ღ</option>
    <option>ყ</option>
    <option>შ</option>
    <option>ჩ</option>
    <option>ც</option>
    <option>ძ</option>
    <option>წ</option>
    <option>ჭ</option>
    <option>ხ</option>
    <option>ჯ</option>
    <option>ჰ</option>
    <option>а</option>
    <option>б</option>
    <option>в</option>
    <option>г</option>
    <option>д</option>
    <option>е</option>
    <option>ж</option>
    <option>з</option>
    <option>и</option>
    <option>к</option>
    <option>л</option>
    <option>м</option>
    <option>н</option>
    <option>о</option>
    <option>п</option>
    <option>р</option>
    <option>с</option>
    <option>т</option>
    <option>у</option>
    <option>ф</option>
    <option>х</option>
    <option>ц</option>
    <option>ч</option>
    <option>ш</option>
    <option>щ</option>
    <option>э</option>
    <option>ю</option>
    <option>я</option>

<option value="other">0-9</option>
</alphaindex>
```

english,georgia and russian language alphabets

here is image Looks this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWH5F.jpg

I want this,

english language in new line
georgian language in new line
russian language in new line

but I can't make this. please help

this is alphaindex php code

```
<?php
/**
* @package   com_zoo
* @author    YOOtheme http://www.yootheme.com
* @copyright Copyright (C) YOOtheme GmbH
* @license   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html GNU/GPL
*/

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// include assets css/js
if (strtolower(substr($GLOBALS['app']->getTemplate(), 0, 3)) != 'yoo') {
    $this->app->document->addStylesheet('assets:css/reset.css');
}
$this->app->document->addStylesheet($this->template->resource.'assets/css/zoo.css');

$css_class = $this->application->getGroup().'-'.$this->template->name;

?>

<div id="yoo-zoo" class="yoo-zoo <?php echo $css_class; ?> <?php echo $css_class.'-alphaindex'; ?>">

    <?php if ($this->params->get('template.show_alpha_index')) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->partial('alphaindex'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->params->get('template.show_title')) : ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php

        // render categories
        $has_categories = false;
        if (!empty($this->selected_categories)) {
            $has_categories = true;
            echo $this->partial('categories');
        }

    ?>

    <?php

        // render items
        if (count($this->items)) {
            echo $this->partial('items', compact('has_categories'));
        }

    ?>

</div>
```

**solved**

```
  $html = array();

        // create html
        foreach ($this->_index as $key => $char) {
            if (isset($this->_objects[$key]) && count($this->_objects[$key])) {
                $html[] = '<a href="'.JRoute::_($this->app->route->alphaindex($app->id, $key)).'" style="background:#7ea33e; padding:3px; margin:3px; border-radius:3px;" title="'.$char.'">'.$char.'</a>';
            } else {
                $html[] = '<span  title="'.$char.'">'.$char.'</span>';
                if( $char == "z" || $char == "ჰ" ) {  

                $html[] = ' <div style="width:100%; display: inline-block;"></div>';
            } 

            }
        }

        return implode($html);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't set it to the xml file, you have to check php code to add the appropriate line breaks. Something like: if($counter == 14) { echo "<br>"; }

Comment: You have to find the file that $this->partial('alphaindex'); is being created. Please remove the answer and add the code editing the main post.

Comment: how to add code editing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check **$char** variable and add a line break. So after:

```
$html[] = '<a href="'.JRoute::_($this->app->route->alphaindex($app->id, $key)).'" style="background:#7ea33e; padding:3px; margin:3px; border-radius:3px;" title="'.$char.'">'.$char.'</a>';
```

You have to add:

```
if( $char == "r26" || $char == "r26" ) {
  $html[] = '<br>';
}
```

Your code after this addition would be:

```
foreach ($this->_index as $key => $char) {

        if (isset($this->_objects[$key]) && count($this->_objects[$key])) {
            $html[] = '<a href="'.JRoute::_($this->app->route->alphaindex($app->id, $key)).'" style="background:#7ea33e; padding:3px; margin:3px; border-radius:3px;" title="'.$char.'">'.$char.'</a>';
            if( $char == "r26" || $char == "r26" ) { $html[] = '<br>'; }
        } else {
            $html[] = '<span  title="'.$char.'">'.$char.'</span>';
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If you don't have basic php skills to check **$char** echo and add the appropriate values inside r26 fields that would be hard to get help from SO users.

Comment: Are you sure that $char contain this values? you could add a echo $char. " -"; to check the appropriate value that you have to add in your check.

Comment: yes echo $char; results is abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzაბგდევზთიკლმნოპჟრსტუფქღყშჩცძწჭხჯჰабвгдежзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщэюя0-9

Comment: Great so instead of r26 you have to add the last char name.

Comment: can you show me how? full code? sorry for my bad english and php :( thank you

Comment: can you see my post top?

Comment: I am sorry have finished with this task. You have to learn php in order to solve your simple problem, it's hard for me to do something else from here.